# Samba shares empty and not writeable when browsing OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, centos, network-shares, samba, file-server

When I mount a Samba share it works, but it doesn't show me any files, even though they exist on the server, I also cannot write files to the share either.

The server is CentOS 6.4, running Samba. Clients are 10.8.

1. I can mount a share from the server using: `smb://<ip>/<share name>`
2. I can: `telnet <ip> 445` successfully
3. user who mounts the share owns it in this case.

smb.conf:

```
#======================= Global Settings =====================================
[global]
interfaces = eth1 lo
bind interfaces only = yes
workgroup = WORKGROUP
security = share
map to guest = bad user
#============================ Share Definitions ==============================
[MyShare]
user="<user>"
force user = <user>
comment = MyShare Files
path = /drobo/users/<user>
browsable = yes
writable = yes
read only = no
public = yes
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
```

What changes need to be made so that the files that already exist can be seen as well as allowing write permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Stop using security=share ! - see my blog post [Samba and guest shares with "security = user"](http://blog.realcomputerguy.com/2010/12/samba-and-guest-shares-with-security.html)

Also suggest you simplify your share definition:

1. Drop user= - it's not valid (testparm should tell you that)
2. Drop force user = - that is if you want guest access
3. Drop writable= - it's a synonym for read only= - you don't need both
4. Drop public=yes, it's usable but better to replace with guest ok=yes of which it is a synonym for.
5. Drop the mask entries until you know what you're doing.